# Problems with the PHP script to generate the licenses in Aquatic Prime

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I am using Aquatic Prime to generate licenses for my application. I have no problems producing an validating licenses using the Aquatic Prime developer application, however I have not had any success with the PHP script. I am using Paypal as the payment mechanism, and this appears to have no problems as the license files I receiving have the correct data. The problem is that the license files that are being generated do not validate because the license numbers appears to be incorrect. 
It seems to be the PHP script generating the licenses is not working correctly, but with so many users of Aquatic Prime I must assume that I am doing something wrong but it is not clear what. My problem is that I can't find the source code for the Cocoa version of Aquatic Prime Developer so I'm not sure what algorithm is being used by that to generate valid licenses. If I have that then I can work through the PHP script to find out what I doing incorrectly. 
Does anyone have any pointers either with regard to Aquatic Prime Developer or with regard to the PHP script that might help address my problems.

Thanks for the help.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a known issue. Using the C-version of the signature generator (Makefile is included) will solve this. You will need shell-access on the web server to compile the .c file and generate the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, and other people too, although I found very few complaining about this problem (I tried to contact the author of Aquatic Prime, with no success).

The PHP script has a bug which prevents its from generating correct licences when any piece of information of the licence file contains a non ASCII-7 character: either the name of your App, the first or last name of the client. This means you will have problems some times with names of people of Europe, and every time for people of Asia.
I had not the time yet to figure out how to fix it. I guess if you can use the C version of the getSignature() function, instead of PHP version, it will work.

The code for the Aquatic Prime Developer app is not included, but you can be confident that it uses the same algorithm than the Aquatic Prime framework. Indeed, any licence that I generate with Aquatic Prime Developer works with my App.